# Input field not updating

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a tip calculator using HTML and Javascript and each time the user changes the input field for the meal cost and tip amount, I have to validate whether or not it is a number and if it is, I have to cut down the number to 2 decimal places.

```
   <script>
            function validateMealCost(mealCharge){
                var mealCost = document.getElementById(mealCharge).value;
                if (isNaN(mealCost)){
                    alert("The cost of the meal has to be a number.");
                    location.reload();
                }
                mealCost = mealCost.toFixed(2);
                return mealCost;
            }

            function validateTipPercent(tipPercent){
                var tipPercent = document.getElementById(tipPercent).value;
                if (isNaN(tipPercent)){
                    alert("The tip percentage has to be a number.");
                    location.reload();
                }
                if (tipPercent >= 1.0){
                    alert("You are very generous.");
                }
                tipPercent = tipPercent.toFixed(2);
                return tipPercent;
            } 

            function calculateTipAmount(mealCharge, tipPercent){
                var tipAmount;
                var mealCost = document.getElementById(mealCharge);
                var tipPercentage = document.getElementById(tipPercent);
                tipAmount = mealCost * tipPercentage;
                document.getElementById('tipAmount').value = tipAmount;
            }
        </script>


        <input type="text" id="mealCharge" onchange="validateMealCost('mealCharge');" />
            <input type="text" id="tipPercentage" onchange="validateTipPercent('tipPercentage');" />
    <button onclick="calculateTipAmount('mealCharge','tipPercentage');">Calculate</button>
    <input type="text" id="tipAmount" style="text-align: right;"/>
```

I don't think it is taking the values that are edited using toFixed() and also the field tipAmount is showing NaN. How can I fix these errors?

Comment: also - when you get  the tip percentage - won't you need to actually divide that by 100 to get a percentage. At the moment if the order is for 10 dollars and you enter 10 into the tip then the expected result will be 10*10, rather than 10*0.10.

Comment: @gavgrif, I will add a label to show "type in decimal form". Thanks.

Comment: my point would be that this line  is incorrect " tipAmount = mealCost * tipPercentage" - it should be  "tipAmount = mealCost * (tipPercentage/100)"; then you can do" mealCost+=tipAmount" to get the updated mela cost plut tip included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
 <script>
            function validateMealCost(mealCharge){
                var mealCost = document.getElementById(mealCharge).value;
                if (isNaN(mealCost)){
                    alert("The cost of the meal has to be a number.");
                    location.reload();
                }
                mealCost = parseInt(mealCost).toFixed(2);
                return mealCost;
            }

            function validateTipPercent(tipPercent){
                var tipPercent = document.getElementById(tipPercent).value;
                if (isNaN(tipPercent)){
                    alert("The tip percentage has to be a number.");
                    location.reload();
                }
                if (tipPercent >= 1.0){
                    alert("You are very generous.");
                }
                tipPercent = parseInt(tipPercent).toFixed(2);
                return tipPercent;
            } 

            function calculateTipAmount(mealCharge, tipPercent){
                var tipAmount;
                var mealCost = document.getElementById(mealCharge).value;
                var tipPercentage = document.getElementById(tipPercent).value;
                tipAmount = mealCost * tipPercentage;
                document.getElementById('tipAmount').value = tipAmount;
            }
        </script>


        <input type="text" id="mealCharge" onchange="validateMealCost('mealCharge');" />
            <input type="text" id="tipPercentage" onchange="validateTipPercent('tipPercentage');" />
    <button onclick="calculateTipAmount('mealCharge','tipPercentage');">Calculate</button>
    <input type="text" id="tipAmount" style="text-align: right;"/>
```

The `validateMealCost` and `validateTipPercent` functions lacked a `parseInt` to turn the values to numbers, and the `calculateTipAmount` function lacked a `.value`, turning it to NaN.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it

Answer (score 1):

you need to parse the inputs - all the text inputs will provide strings and therefore cannot be compared to others numbers as a number not can they be in that form nor can they be used for calculations. Also note that even if you have used a number to do calculations, using .toFixed() will convert that number to a string.

For example - you will need to use parseInt or parseFloat which will return a number:

```
var tipPercent = parseInt(document.getElementById(tipPercent).value);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not updating because you need to declare the input **before** the script. So the simple fix for this would be to move the entire `<script>` tag to below the last occurrence of `<input>`.

You can emulate the result using the [W3Schools Tryit Editor](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic) and pasting a snippet of your code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
The content of the body element is displayed in your browser.
<input type="text" id="tipAmount" />
<script>
document.getElementById('tipAmount').value = 5*5;
document.getElementById('tipAmount2').value = 5*5;
</script>
<input type="text" id="tipAmount2" />
</body>

</html>
```

Notice how the code only updates `tipAmount` and not `tipAmount2`.

Comment: No, that is not the problem. My example fixes the issue without doing this.